# bash - using lftp to mirror specific files from remote folder

Tags: bash, remote

I want to mirror files from a remote directory via ftp.

The following code works:

```
lftp -c 'open ipaddress; user myusername mypassword; mirror -e /files/ /home/user/files/retrieve/; quit'
```

However, I want to be able to specify the age and size of the files that I need to retrieve like `mtime -2 and -size +10M`

Where would I add these values?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
lftp -c 'open ipaddress; user myusername mypassword; mirror -r -N now-2days /files/ /home/user/files/retrieve/; quit'
```

where

`-r` is 'don't go to subdirectories';
 `-N` is 'files newer or created in the last 2 days'